# '>' is not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python

I started learning coding quite recently and this is my first question here, so pardon me if the question is too silly.

I started learning Python like yesterday and I am stuck at this problem, when the `if` statement is being executed, i get an error stating that `>` is not supported between instances of `str` and `int`.

I know a bit of JavaScript, and I think that the variable `age` is being treated as a string, but shouldn't it be considered an integer if the input is a number.

What should I change here, to make it work in the desired way.

```
name = input("Enter your name:")
print("Hello, " +name)
age = input("Please enter your age:")
if age > 3:
    print("You are allowed to use the internet.")
elif age <= 3:
    print("You are still a kid what are you doing here.")
```

I expect the program to print the respective statements according to the age I input, but i get an error at the start of the `if` statement, stating that the `>` operator cannot be used to compare a string and an integer.

Comment: Python, although dynamically typed like JS, is stricter about what it allows in terms of comparing different types. `age` here will indeed be a string, and unlike JS the `>` operator won't automatically convert strings to number or numbers to strings for you.

Comment: @Robinzigmond note that in Python 2, this comparison would be valid, but basically nonsense. It will be compared lexicographically based on the type name. Thankfully that "feature" was removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the traceback said, `age` is a string because it has just been "inputted" by the user. Unlike C, there is no method to do something like `scanf("%d", &age)`, so you need to manually cast age to an integer with `age = int(age)`.

```
name = input("Enter your name:")
print("Hello, " +name)
age = input("Please enter your age:")
# do exception handling to make sure age is in integer format
age = int(age)
```

Answer (score 1):

the comparison operator is comparing a string with integer. So convert your sting to int before comparison

```
name = input("Enter your name:")
print("Hello, " +name)
age = input("Please enter your age:")
if int(age) > 3:
    print("You are allowed to use the internet.")
elif int(age) <= 3:
    print("You are still a kid what are you doing here.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert age into `int` by default it is `string`

```
name = input("Enter your name:")
print("Hello, " +name)
age = int(input("Please enter your age:"))
if age > 3:
    print("You are allowed to use the internet.")
elif age <= 3:
    print("You are still a kid what are you doing here.")
```